# How are python applications uninstalled in linux?

Tags: linux, python, uninstall

I've been wanting to ask this for forever.

What is the common way that python programs or applications uninstalled?
Authors do not seem to include a way to uninstall their package.

This is not about the 'python' named packages themselves, but the programs that were installed
with and use python as in '`python setup.py install`'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no such good options other than removing the python installation stuff manually and revert back file changes made by the installation. You are able to record the files changed by using --record switch during the installation.I use pip to do uninstall sometimes.`pip uninstall package name`. for this you have to install pip. to install pip in linux, try this `sudo easy_install Distribute` and if it is windows then refer this [link](http://blog.troygrosfield.com/2010/12/18/installing-easy_install-and-pip-for-python/)